# angular two-way binding not working when called with a timeout

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, underscore.js

So I have an HTML template inside which I have following angular expression `{{player.score}}`. The initial score of the player that is stored in a scope object is correctly rendered in the place of the expression.

Now, I have a button click on which this score needs to be updated. If I simple update the players score with a hardcoded value it works correctly:

```
$scope.updateScore = function (){
     $scope.player.score = 1000; //this is updated without any issues
};
```

But my problem is that my player score is a complicated calculation, which needs me to use `_.defer`. So when I wrap my earlier code (for testing) inside `_.defer` it does not work:

```
 $scope.updateScore = function (){
         _.defer(function() {
              $scope.player.score = 5000; //this is not updated...
         });
    };
```

The way I understand `_.defer` it is just underscores wrapper for `setTimeout`. I would expect that after whatever delay `_.defer` uses, when it finally gets around to updating the score, then it will get reflected in the HTML due to the Angular two-way binding.

But this is not happening only when `_.defer` is used, else it works as expected. Also `_.defer` is updating the Angular object because if I do a `console.log(player.score)` in the deferred code, then after a few seconds in the console I do see the update score (5000).

Can any angular/Javascript experts help me understand what I am doing incorrect and how I can fix it. Please note that removing `_.defer` is not really an option because of various technical/legacy reasons.

I am just trying to figure out why when the object is updated in a deferred manner, the Angular does not update the view.

Any pointers are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Shouldn't `player.score` be `$scope.player.score`?

Comment: yes it is - player.scope was a typo.

Comment: ``_.defer()`` doesn't trigger the digest cycle. You should do that 'manually' after you assign something new to your scope. Alternatively you can also use ``$timeout`` which does that anyway.

Comment: @GuidoKitzing: can you give me an example of how I can do that in my particular use case? Much appreciated

Comment: Try using ``$scope.$apply()`` after your assignment in ``_.defer()``

Answer (score 2):

Angular doesn't "know" about this defer so even if the value gets updated, it won't appear in the view until the next digest loop. 
You can inject [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) to your controller and use it like this:

```
_.defer(function() {
     $timeout(function() {
          $scope.player.score = 5000; //this is not updated...
     });
});
```

You should also read about deferred objects in angular (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q)

Answer (score 1):

`_.defer` takes the code out of the scope of the angular digest, because it internally calls `setTimeout`.

You either need to manually kick off a digest inside the deferred function so angular rebinds at that point, using [$scope.$apply](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply):

```
$scope.updateScore = function (){
     _.defer(function() {
          player.score = 5000;
          $scope.$apply();
     });
};
```

or you need to keep the callback inside the angular scope, probably by using [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) (but remember to inject `$timeout` into your controller/directive):

```
$scope.updateScore = function (){
     $timeout(function() {
          player.score = 5000;
     }, 1); // or 0, but _.defer passes 1
};
```

I would go with option 2 from preference, and I personally can't see how using `_.defer` can be required over this, but of course it is up to you.